# Smart Contract : .methods.request().send() doesn't display anything

Tags: node.js, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have the following problem:

I've written a smart contract on remix :

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract anotherTry {

 function Hello() external pure returns (string memory) {
    return "Hello World !!!";
}


}
```

And I compiled it and then I got its WEB3DEPLOY data and added it in my Geth console.The contract address that I received and the ABI from the remix website I used them just like this :

```
//addr = the contract address received from the Geth console
//abit = obviously,the ABI
//account = a random & valid account address(I've tried with addr too...who knows maybe it could work)

let MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, addr);
MyContract.methods.Hello().send({ from: account }).then(receipt => { console.log("SUCCESS"); });
```

The problem is that I don't receive any message but I receive the circular structure with functions and stuff when I try

```
console.log(MyContract.methods);
```

Any idea why I can't "connect" to my smart contract?
I'm using NodeJS with web3 1.0.0 & Geth

Answer (score 0):

I solved it,

was actually a problem with the web3 provider declaration and I should've called methods.request().call() instead of .send()

Thank you for help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

To add some more details to the above correct answer, to determine whether to use `call` vs `send` take a look at the contract method signature, if it is a `view` or `pure` it doesn't alter state and you must use `call`. Other methods without such a signature or `payable` alters state on the blockchain and so is a transaction and one must pay ethers for gas. These types of methods must be called with `send`.

Ire writes clearly about this here https://bitsofco.de/calling-smart-contract-functions-using-web3-js-call-vs-send/